# htaccess redirect old address to new address not working

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with redirecting address from : http://www.example.com/za/en/ to http://www.example.com/gb/en/. It doesn't work now. Thank you.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/za/en/$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/gb/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: what is the error you face?

Comment: @NirMH It doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You need this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/za/en/(.*)$ /gb/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match URI in `HTTP_HOST` variable. You can only match host/domain name there.

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^za/(en.*)$ /gb/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```